# Can't see homebrew files

Tags: python, file, path, anaconda

So I recently downloaded a package and it is stored at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/package`, yet nothing comes up when I search this in my finder. On the other hand, all of my other anaconda packages are stored in `/Users/Me/opt/anaconda3` and I can see them. Why can't I find this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the link in the “Edit:” in the question I’m about to link no longer contains the quoted text, we at least have the quote (and could probably check via archive.org if we really cared), from [macos - How to view Root directory and subdirectories in Finder? - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34871/how-to-view-root-directory-and-subdirectories-in-finder):

> The Finder and the Terminal show different contents for the root directory. Some items in the root directory are not visible in the Finder. This reduces visual clutter and enhances simplicity. If you are familiar with a UNIX-style command line you can use Terminal to view all items in a directory.

You can access it in Finder by using the Go to Folder keyboard shortcut: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>